# Getting location address without display any map

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dictionary, location, arcgis

I am doing a windows phone 7 application with map location service (I am using ArcGis at the moment). I wanted to know if it is possible to get the current location address of the user without displaying any map. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you would need to do is get the location of the user.  I have never developed on Windows Phone, but a quick google searched yielded [this result](http://mws580.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/get-location-on-windows-phone-7/).

Once you have the users location, you should proceed to call the [Reverse Geocode Rest API](http://nsdemo.esri.com/arcgis/sdk/rest/reverse.html) and input the users coordinates.

The result of the Reverse Geocode operation should yield the address of the current user without displaying a map.